# Angular.js HTTP Concatenation - Changing URL - Breaks Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geolocation

Update. Not really a duplicate as concatenation, as I understand it, is not working in this case.

I've tried the following as kindly provided by Baszz below but it seems to break angular. Test expressions I have showing latitude, longitude and the postcode in the view show the expression code instead when I use this:

```
$http.get('//api.postcodes.io/postcodes?limit=1&lon=' + 
              $geolocation.position.coords.longitude + 
              '&lat=' +  
              $geolocation.position.coords.latitude);
```

---

I'm using the ngGeolocation module for Angular to find the latitude and longitude of the user in order to work out the postcode using postcodes.io.

Latitude is at: `$geolocation.position.coords.latitude`
Longitude is at: `$geolocation.position.coords.longitude`

The following example gives a postcode result:

```
$http.get('//api.postcodes.io/postcodes?limit=1&lon=-0.1276250&lat=51.5033630')
```

I want to insert the longitude and latitude into the above line of code.
How can this be done?

The complete code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGeolocation']);

myApp.controller('geolocCtrl', ['$scope', '$geolocation', '$http',
    function($scope, $geolocation, $http) {
      $scope.$geolocation = $geolocation


          // basic usage
          $geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(location) {
            $scope.location = location
          });

          // regular updates
          $geolocation.watchPosition({
            timeout: 60000,
            maximumAge: 2,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
          });


       $scope.testing = "300";

          $scope.coords = $geolocation.position.coords; // this is regularly updated
          $scope.error = $geolocation.position.error; // this becomes truthy, and has 'code' and 'message' if an error occurs

          $http.get('//api.postcodes.io/postcodes?limit=1&lon=-0.1276250&lat=51.5033630')

.success(function (data) {

           $scope.postcode = data.result[0].postcode;
           var postcode2 = $scope.postcode


        })
        .error(function (data, status) {

            console.log(data);

        });


        }]);
```

Comment: When Angular "breaks" and shows unevaluated Angular expressions in the HTML usually means there is an error message on the browser console telling you what is wrong with your code :) If you still need help, you should  edit this question and add that error message.

Comment: It was a problem with the ngGeolocation module.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave I would say:

```
        $http.get('//api.postcodes.io/postcodes?limit=1&lon=' + 
              $geolocation.position.coords.longitude + 
              '&lat=' +  
              $geolocation.position.coords.latitude);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - breaks angular (showing expression code in the view.)

Comment: How about you show us some more code or learn more about AngularJS first?

Comment: I was trying to keep it relevant but sure.
I've added the complete code.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, it has gotten me a little further on with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the module.